# manipulate a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql query that returns me in PHP an array like this

```
array(
    [0] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [1] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [2] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [3] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [4] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [5] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [6] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [7] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
    [8] -> ([cred_id],[date],[value]);
);
```

and so on. Cred_id can be the same for different array items. So I'd like to turn this array into something like this:

```
array(
[cred_id]->(([date],[value]),([date],[value]),([date],[value]))
[cred_id]->(([date],[value]),([date],[value]))
);
```

This way if I know a [cred_id] value I can do a foreach loop between all the date-value pair I have extracted from the database.

Is there a smart php function that I can use or do I have to go with a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($creds as $cred){
    $new_creds[$cred['cred_id']][]= array($cred[date],$cred[value]);
}
```

that actually is my smartest idea on how to get this result?

Comment: Although you could probably use some smart mapping function, this looks good. Note that you do need `$new_creds[$cred[cred_id]][] = ...`.

Comment: [`array_column`](https://php.net/manualfunction.array-column.php) maybe.

Comment: Do quote your array key names: `$cred['cred_id']`. Otherwise they will be assumed as constants.

Comment: @MarkusAO yes, it's a typo here. Will update the question

Comment: Your smartest idea is smart enough!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than looping using [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you can make use of [**array_walk**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function like below

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/384211)

```
$output1 = array(); 
array_walk($array,function($item,$key) use (&$output1){
     $output1[$item['cred_id']][]=array($item['date'],$item['value']);     
});

// OR  

$output2 = array();
array_map(function($item) use (&$output2){
     $output2[$item['cred_id']][]=array($item['date'],$item['value']);
},$array);

print_r($output1);
print_r($output2);
```

Comment: The OP's code works fine, you are just complicating it.

Comment: @AkshayHegde foreach is better in terms of performance compared to array_map or array_walk and in this situation speed is important since there is a strong amount of data returned by the query

Comment: @LelioFaieta : That is true, but since you asked for some smart php function, I showed these